# Django showing incorrect url but displaying the correct content

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am having an issue with some Django code; I have a form at mysite/edit-home, which updates some content which will be displayed on the index page at the root of mysite/. When the form correctly submits, it renders the index template, and all content is correctly displayed, but the url does not change, and instead shows /mysite/edit-home still despite showing a different page.

I'm wondering if there's any reason why this will not change? I have tried to remove as much information from the below as it is a pretty large site already so don't want to clutter the issue. There are no issues other than this across all the other pages and databasing, etc, and this issue only is showing the wrong url and does not affect the content of the page. Thanks for all the help.

I have tried most combinations of changing urls files, and changing the method of rendering, ie using a reverse etc but it won't say anything besides /mysite/edit-home rather than /mysite/ or /.

Edit:

I have now found that the same error will occur for a very similar situation: when editing the about page, on /mysite/edit-about, and rendering 'mysite/about.html' template, the correct page content is displayed, but the url shows mysite/edit-about, much the same as the other issue.

Below is the code:

mysite/project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('mysite/', include('mysite.urls')),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('', views.index, name='index')
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
...

app_name = 'mysite'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    ...
    path('edit-home/', views.edit_home, name='edit-home'),
    ...
]
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def edit_home(request):
    ...
        context_dict['errors'] = errors
        if not errors:
            context_dict = {'categories': Category.objects.all()}
            content = PageContents.objects.all()
            if content:
                content = content[0]
            context_dict['category'] = None
            context_dict['content'] = content
            return render(request, 'mysite/index.html', context_dict)
```